# Join data frames by row

Tags: r, join, row, dataframe, bind

I have different `data.frames` of 1 row that I would like to join to form one big `data.frame`. The thing is that I want my `colnames` to go  from `jan 2002` to `dic 2011`, and fill these columns with my `data frames` even if for one column there is no value. Examples on data.frames (There can be with "discrete" dates):

df1:

```
ene 2002 ene 2002 feb 2002 feb 2002 mar 2002 mar 2002 
    69       MA       38       MA     38       MA
```

df2:

```
ago 2004 ago 2004 sep 2004 sep 2004 oct 2004 oct 2004 
   114       MB      102       MB       49       M
```

df3:

```
oct 2011 oct 2011 nov 2011 nov 2011 dic 2011 dic 2011
10       A        9     A           20       MA
```

df4("Discrete data.frame"):

```
jan 2008 jan 2008  jul 2009 jul 2009 dic 2010  dic 2010
20          MA       200       B       100       MB
```

Data.frame wanted (desire Output):

```
ene 2002 ene 2002 feb 2002 feb 2002 mar 2002 mar 2002...ago 2004 ago 2004 sep 2004 sep 2004 oct 2004 oct 2004...jan 2008 jan 2008...jul 2009 jul 2009...dic 2010  dic 2010... oct 2011 oct 2011 nov 2011 nov 2011 dic 2011 dic 2011
    69       MA       38       MA     38       MA          NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA         NA       NA         NA        NA          NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA                             
    NA       NA       NA       NA     NA       NA          114      MB       102      MB       49       M         NA       NA         NA       NA         NA        NA          NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
    NA       NA       NA       NA     NA       NA          NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        NA       NA         NA       NA         NA        NA          10       A        9        A        20       MA
    NA       NA       NA       NA     NA       NA          NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        20       MA         200      B          100       MB          NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

In this example all other columns with no value would be `NA`: For example ene 2003 feb 2003 ..... nov 2005 dic 2005 ...... all month in year 2006 or 2007 ( Just saying random month that were not in the example but I want them to appear in my output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plyr`'s `rbind.fill`

```
rbind.fill(list(df1,df2,df3,df4))
```

Note: duplicate column names (ex: feb 2002) will be changed to `feb 2002.1`.

**Edit:** This is what I get:

```
#   ene2002 ene2002.1 feb2002 feb2002.1 mar2002 mar2002.1 ago2004 ago2004.1 sep2004
# 1      69        MA      38        MA      38        MA      NA      <NA>      NA
# 2      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>     114        MB     102
# 3      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA
# 4      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA
#   sep2004.1 oct2004 oct2004.1 oct2011 oct2011.1 nov2011 nov2011.1 dic2011 dic2011.1
# 1      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>
# 2        MB      49         M      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>
# 3      <NA>      NA      <NA>      10         A       9         A      20        MA
# 4      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>
#   jan2008 jan2008.1 jul2009 jul2009.1 dic2010 dic2010.1
# 1      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>
# 2      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>
# 3      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>      NA      <NA>
# 4      20        MA     200         B     100        MB
```

Comment: That's what I want, but contrary as you say, duplicated column names have disappeared ! I don't know why.... the output just throws me the first unrepeated dates..... what could be wrong ?

Comment: @TomásAyala, I've pasted the output I get. I've the duplicate columns as well. Not quite sure what you're saying.. Could you elaborate?